# Cannot extend LVM disk partition

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm trying to add more space to my hosting, I've got an eCloud VM, I've added 10 more GB via dashboard (it uses VMware tools) and now support tells me that increase has been allocated to the system:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 167.5 GB, 167503724544 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 20364 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xb50df193

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdb1 1 3916 31455238+ 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2 3917 12401 68155762+ 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sdb3 12402 20364 63962797+ 8e Linux LVM
```

And I need to extend the LVM partition to add the new partition to the partition I want to be increased.

I've followed [their guide](https://docs.ukfast.co.uk/operatingsystems/linux/basics/lvm-extend.html) but I'm getting some errors and WHM still doesn't see added space.

That's my setup:

```
# pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda2  eCloud lvm2 a--u  9.80g    0
  /dev/sdb1  eCloud lvm2 a--u 30.00g    0
  /dev/sdb2  eCloud lvm2 a--u 65.00g    0
  /dev/sdb3  eCloud lvm2 a--u 50.00g    0
# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  eCloud   4   2   0 wz--n- 154.79g    0
# lvs
  LV   VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root eCloud -wi-ao---- 153.79g
  swap eCloud -wi-ao----   1.00g

# dmesg
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 20971520 512-byte logical blocks: (10.7 GB/10.0 GiB)
sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] 327155712 512-byte logical blocks: (167 GB/156 GiB)
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 31 00 00 00
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Cache data unavailable
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 31 00 00 00
sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Cache data unavailable
sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Cache data unavailable
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sda:
sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Cache data unavailable
sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sdb: sda1 sda2
 sdb1 sdb2 sdb3
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Cache data unavailable
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Cache data unavailable
sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk

# fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1305 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000301ba

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          26      204800   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              26        1306    10279936   8e  Linux LVM
```

The guide says in this case it's additional disk and I need to create a new physical volume for the new device (sda) so that we can use it in LVM, but when I do that I get this message:

```
# pvcreate /dev/sda
  Device /dev/sda not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

How to make the new space visible in the WHM? I don't get what's wrong...

Also this is what WHM is showing:
[image: Disk space in WHM]

And this is the hosting dashboard:
[image: eCloud Details]

Answer (score 1):

I think they extended the /dev/sdb disk

> `Disk /dev/sdb: 167.5 GB`

Which is ~156 GiB. If you check /dev/sdbX sizes, you are currently using ~145 GiB on that disk. So there is still ~10GiB free

> ```
>   /dev/sdb1  eCloud lvm2 a--u 30.00g    0
>   /dev/sdb2  eCloud lvm2 a--u 65.00g    0
>   /dev/sdb3  eCloud lvm2 a--u 50.00g    0
> ```

In that case you shold make new lvm partition /dev/sdb4

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
```

Get through process and then you create pv on /dev/sdb4

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb4
```

Finally add /dev/sdb4 to volume group:

```
vgextend eCloud /dev/sdb4
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I've tried adding primary partition before but I get an error saying "No free sectors available"... Should I create an extended partition then?

Comment: maybe you just need to do
"pvresize /dev/sdb"
to make LVM recognize that PV size has changed

Comment: Strange, I got this: # pvresize /dev/sdb
  Failed to find device for physical volume "/dev/sdb".
  0 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized